# c#:boolean values not getting converted when coverting from object to xml

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to convert object to xml. i have written a class which converts object to xml. in my object i have boolean and string variables. But when i convert only string variable a getting converted and not boolean. Please help me to resolve this issue. Below is my code.

```
LocateRequest stockLoanRequest = new LocateRequest();
stockLoanRequest.acceptManualApproval = false;
stockLoanRequest.acceptPartial = false;
stockLoanRequest.market = "US";
stockLoanRequest.cashOrSwap = cashOrSwapType.CASH;
stockLoanRequest.requestedQuantity = request.shares.ToString();
stockLoanRequest.requestorReference = request.locateId;
stockLoanRequest.securityId = request.symbol;
stockLoanRequest.securityIdentifierType = securityIdentifierType.TICKER;
return stockLoanRequest;
```

Convert object to xml code:

```
public static string convertRequestToXML(Object obj)
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = null;
     StringWriterUTF8 sw = new StringWriterUTF8();

     XmlTextWriter tw = null;
     try
     {
         serializer = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());
         tw = new XmlTextWriter(sw);
         tw.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
         serializer.Serialize(tw, obj);
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         //Handle Exception Code
     }
     finally
     {
         sw.Close();
         if (tw != null)
         {
             tw.Close();
         }
     }

     return sw.ToString();
 }
```

Output to xml looks like below:

```
<LocateRequests>
    <LocateRequest securityId="IBM" securityIdentifierType="TICKER" market="US" requestedQuantity="1" requestorReference="34" />
</LocateRequests>
```

I don't see the boolean values *acceptManualApproval* and *acceptPartial* getting in the above output.

Below is the locate request class:

```html
public partial class LocateRequest 
{        
    private bool acceptManualApprovalField;       
    private bool acceptManualApprovalFieldSpecified;       
    private bool acceptPartialField;       
    private bool acceptPartialFieldSpecified;      
    private string securityIdField;        
    private securityIdentifierType securityIdentifierTypeField;       
    private string marketField;        
    private string requestedQuantityField;        
    private string requestorReferenceField;        
    private cashOrSwapType cashOrSwapField;        
    private bool cashOrSwapFieldSpecified;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public bool acceptManualApproval {
        get {
            return this.acceptManualApprovalField;
        }
        set {
            this.acceptManualApprovalField = value;
        }
    }
    
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool acceptManualApprovalSpecified {
        get {
            return this.acceptManualApprovalFieldSpecified;
        }
        set {
            this.acceptManualApprovalFieldSpecified = value;
        }
    }
    
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public bool acceptPartial {
        get {
            return this.acceptPartialField;
        }
        set {
            this.acceptPartialField = value;
        }
    }
    
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool acceptPartialSpecified {
        get {
            return this.acceptPartialFieldSpecified;
        }
        set {
            this.acceptPartialFieldSpecified = value;
        }
    }
    
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute(DataType="token")]
    public string securityId {
        get {
            return this.securityIdField;
        }
        set {
            this.securityIdField = value;
        }
    }
    
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public securityIdentifierType securityIdentifierType {
        get {
            return this.securityIdentifierTypeField;
        }
        set {
            this.securityIdentifierTypeField = value;
        }
    }
    
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute(DataType="token")]
    public string market {
        get {
            return this.marketField;
        }
        set {
            this.marketField = value;
        }
    }
    
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute(DataType="positiveInteger")]
    public string requestedQuantity {
        get {
            return this.requestedQuantityField;
        }
        set {
            this.requestedQuantityField = value;
        }
    }
    
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute(DataType="token")]
    public string requestorReference {
        get {
            return this.requestorReferenceField;
        }
        set {
            this.requestorReferenceField = value;
        }
    }
    
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public cashOrSwapType cashOrSwap {
        get {
            return this.cashOrSwapField;
        }
        set {
            this.cashOrSwapField = value;
        }
    }
    
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool cashOrSwapSpecified {
        get {
            return this.cashOrSwapFieldSpecified;
        }
        set {
            this.cashOrSwapFieldSpecified = value;
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Can you post the code for `LocateRequest` ? XmlSerializer will only serialize public properties, its just to make sure the Booleans are public properties.

Comment: Hi Ben,.. i have put the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem with boolean properties that suffixed by "**Specified**", it's ignore properties without the suffix. for example *acceptPartialSpecified* ignore *acceptPartial* in the xml during serialization.

To resolve the issue, rename all specified properties like ***Specified**PropertyName* or delete them from the class.

> Members with names ending on 'Specified' suffix have special meaning to the XmlSerializer: they control serialization of optional ValueType members and have to be of type System.Boolean.

I hope you find this helpful.

Comment: Thank you Sajid. you are awesome.. it worked.. I really appreciate..

Comment: You're welcome, I was glad to help. Can you accept the answer may be will help others, check how to accept an answer https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers